# Can I invest the advance payment from my homeowners insurance after a total loss?

Tags: united-states, insurance

We recently lost our home to a fire, and the insurance company provided a large advance on our settlement.  It will be a long time before we are able to rebuild and replace most of our stuff.  Can we invest that money now so that it grows until we are ready and able to rebuild?

EDIT: We have a mortgage on the house.

Comment: I guess the chance that it may be _lost_ in an investment might make it so it is ill-advised, or possibly illegal?

Comment: Maybe the question then should have been...is the money mine?  Or does it belong to the insurance company (until final settlement) or does it belong at least in part to the Mortgage holder?

Comment: Yes.  At least a couple of us have suggested this as an improvement but the comments were deleted.

Answer (score 2):

### You can spend it on a holiday if you want

Obviously, double check with your insurer but, in general, when an insurer pays an insured, the money belongs to the insured.

If the policy requires the insurer to rebuild your home, then it’s likely this payment is for lost contents and/or compensation for living expenses/rent while they do so.

It’s equally possible that they aren’t going to rebuild your home - this is an advance while they determine what they owe you and they will pay the rest when they know - it’s then up to you how you use the money. You could rebuild your home, or you could blow it all on hats. Naturally, your mortgagee will have something to say about that.

This is particularly likely if you were underinsured, for example if you had $200k of cover and the damage will cost $400k to repair, they will pay you your insured sum ($200k) and leave you to it.